# Azure DevOps Dashboard - Scheduling email notification with report contents

Tags: azure, azure-devops, notifications, devops, dashboard

Could you please help with the process in Azure DevOps VSTS to automate monthly email notification to specific users to remind them of the updated Bug Reporting along with the bug report content and dashboard.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> automate monthly email notification to specific users to remind them of the updated Bug Reporting along with the bug report content and dashboard

For this issue, I am afraid that the built-in notification of azure devops does not support such a feature, notifications should only support event triggering and not scheduled triggering.

When an **event** occurs in Azure DevOps or TFS, its content is compared with every **subscription** of that event type. If the subscription's filter conditions are met by the event, a notification is generated. **A notification is generated for every subscription/event match.**

The content shown in the notification is designed and we cannot customize it.

Here are some official document you can refer to.

- [Events, subscriptions, and notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/concepts-events-and-notifications?view=azure-devops)
- [About notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops)

In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.